# No auth value after successful login using admin guard

Tags: laravel-6, auth-guard

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is my **config/auth.php** file

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
]
```

Here is my LoginController For Admin Login

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Redirect;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
       use AuthenticatesUsers;
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Function to show login form
     */
    public function fnToShowAdminLoginForm(){
        return view('Admin.Auth.loginForm');
    }

    /**
     * Function to check login credentials 
     */

     public function fnToSubmitAdminLogin(Request $request){
        $messsages = array(
            'emailOrphone.required'=>'You cant leave Email/Phone field empty',
            'password.required'=>'You cant leave password field empty',                   
        );

        $rules = array(
            'emailOrphone'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
        );

        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$messsages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }else{

            if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => filter_var($request->emailOrphone, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ), 'password' => $request->password],true) ){  
                //dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name);////**Here i am getting the auth**                        
                return Redirect::intended('admin/login');
            }else{
                return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['upWorng'=>'Email/Phone Or Password does not match']);
            }
        }

     }


}
```

Here is my route web.php

```
    Route::prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function(){
        Route::get('login','LoginController@fnToShowAdminLoginForm')->name('dologin');
        Route::post('login','LoginController@fnToSubmitAdminLogin');
        Route::get('logout','LogoutController@dologout')->name('dologout');
    });
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
        Route::get('colorList/master','ColorController@index')->name('color');
        Route::post('createColorMaster','ColorController@fnToCreateNewColor')->name('createColor');

    });
```

Here is my controller with hits after successfull login ColorController.php

```
    <?php

       namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

       use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
       use Illuminate\Http\Request;
       use App\Models\Colors;
       use Validator;
       use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
       use Session;

     class ColorController extends Controller
    {
    protected $loggedUser;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
        dd(\Auth::guard('admin')->user());////I am not getting the auth here
        //$this->loggedUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
    }
    public function index(){
        $colors = Colors::orderBy('color','ASC')->get();
        return view('Admin.Master.Color',compact('colors'));
    }   
   }
```

Here is my RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class RedirectIfAuthenticated
    {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {     

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            //dd(Auth::guard($guard));
            if ('admin' === $guard) {
                return redirect(route('admin.color'));
            }
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
   }
```

I can login successfully but when i **redirect()->intended() OR redirect()->to() the Auth::guard('admin')** doesnot store any value. I cant figure it out.
I am using laravel 6.9.0 and have no idea why this not working, where i am doing wrong.Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

Your `LoginController` extends `Controller` and use `AuthenticatesUsers`. It means you have the default laravel auth system. But then, you began to invent own wheel, why? For example, you need to show your Login form instead default. No problem, copy method `showLoginForm` from trait `AuthenticatesUsers` to your `LoginController` and edit return view.

You need to edit validation, copy method `validateLogin` from trait `AuthenticatesUsers` to your `LoginController`. Continue the same way everywhere (Register, Verify etc).

Don't fight the framework, let him to work for you.